# Does debug mode still create the same program in .net?

Tags: visual-studio, file, debugging

I just found out about Release mode in Visual Studio. When I debug my project I can go to my project files and grab the .exe file in the bin folder, this is what I normally use as the finished program. My question is when I do Release Mode instead of Debug Mode, does it generate a better file in this bin folder, or does Debug Mode create the same file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Debug Build contains debug info, and uses less compiler optimizations.
For mathematical heavy applications a debug build is usually slower (and consumes more memory) at run time than a release build.

for best performace a release build is preferred.

Comment: Yeah I know but my question is do these modes only affect how your program runs from visual studio or do they generate different files after running.

Comment: I mean is the file in the bin folder always generated in release mode by visual studio or is it generated from debug mode if you select debug mode in visual studio?

Comment: A debug and release build are compiled differently. therfore the compiled MSIL is different (optimized for debug or optimized for performance). generally a debug build uses less optimizations so it is possible to step trough the code when debugging. Even when you're not debugging, a debug build will miss these optimizations in the compiled assembly or exe. for larger projects you can see differences in file sizes for example.

Comment: So should I keep it on Release mode all the time?

Comment: Use Release builds for production, Debug builds for testing and debugging. (for a small application this doesn't always matter much in performance / memory usage) In a release build for example, not all breakpoints you'll set will hit in the debugger, and it also isn't possible to view all values in the debugger

Comment: Alright good to know. So I don't have to go back through all my old projects and re-compile them in release mode?

Comment: Basically the functionality of your project doesn't change, only the efficiency of the compiled code. for very small and simple programs this doesn't really matter. But when doing complex computations, on large amounts of data (or when COM interop is involved) Debug builds can be thousands of times slower than a release build. If the project is constantly running on a mobile device, it uses more computation and therefore more battery power, etc. You might have a few projects that benefit performance wise. on the other hand, debug builds are easier to reverse engineer (everyone can debug them).

Comment: @Jackson Tarisa, Could you get useful information from Gwen's suggestion? If it is helpful, you could mark his reply as the answer, if not, feel free to share the latest information here. Have a nice day:)